# Suddenly my server reject all POST requests

Tags: javascript, post, bugs

Just go to http://meet-romance.com/test.htm.

The script there is simple, it's a form with a button:

```
<form action="test.htm" method="post">
<input name="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
</form>
```

It doesn't work. Press the button in Firefox and I got connection reset thingy.

I wonder why. It happens since yesterday. I have emigrated all domains that requires POST requests somewhere else.

I suppose a reset of server would fix that only to happen again some other time. So I wonder if anyone has a clue of why. All domains that require post have been moved to another server.

Update: I asked cpanel and the problem is fixed. According to cpanel technician the cause is this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_request.html

I have no idea why it used to work and suddenly fail like that.

Comment: what are you trying on ? The form action is html file so how to get your POST data there ? another is your form have no other fields except the button?

Comment: All POST requests to his server fail, whether the form actually sends any data.

Comment: Hmm... the webhost crm.fdcservers.net has problems too.

Answer (score 1):

When I tested POSTing to your site, my browsers and CURL report that the connection is terminated and that there response is blank.

This behavior makes me think that there is a firewall rule in place that is blocking POST requests.   The only way to resolve the issue would be to ask your web host to remove the firewall rule.

Comment: I see. Everything was just fine a day before. I changed absolutely nothing. Anyone have ever had this problem? I know restarting apache would fix it but I want to know what caused this. Firewall? Firewall reject post requests?

Comment: I doubt that restarting apache would fix it.  Firewall rules are at the operating system level or network level.

Comment: No body could possibly change that firewall. It was working fine before.